# jQuery keydown is not consistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

On pressing ESC key, I want to find href attribute of a link and redirect to that. I'm using following code, it works however it's **not consistent** and I cant figure out why.

There are input form values on the page, if the cursor is in some of the input field and the ESC key is pressed, then it does not work. However, strangely, if I add alert in jquery code then it shows alert and also redirects.

How can I make it redirect even when some of the input field is focused?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).keydown(function(e) {
     var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode);
     if (e.keyCode == 27) {
       var href = $('a').attr('href');
       alert(href); //notice this alert
       if (href) {
         $(location).attr("href", href);
       }
     }
   });
 });
```

In the above code, notice the **alert**. It works if the alert is there, if I remove that line it doesnt work. Here's the demo. (I checked only on Firefox).

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3q56atsm/

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML for reference?

Comment: You have to apply keydown event for the input element.

Comment: Or maybe even better a JSFiddle or something like that to see a working example?

Comment: @DanielSchroederDev a stack snippet is preferable

Comment: @DanielSchroederDev I edited the question and added JSFiddle link.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome

Comment: Also works fine in Chrome in the fiddle - without the alert, pressing escape with/without the input box in focus attempts to redirect.

Comment: yes works in Chrome, doesnt work in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode);
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            var href = $('a').attr('href');
            if (href) {
                $(location).attr("href", href);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="text">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855117/jquery-keydown-is-not-consistent/59855330#59855330">Some test</a>
```

Comment: If you remove `alert(href);` then it will not work, try that. That's exactly my question is.

Comment: no, it just does nothing, but if you keep that alert then it works, which is very strange.

Comment: can you replace alert with console and see what is printing in console

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem , hope it will work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
          keyCode(e);
        });
  });

  function keyCode(event) {
    var x = event.keyCode;
    if (x == 27) {
      alert ("You pressed the Escape key!");
    }else{
      alert("Other Key");
    }
  }
```